# Skin windows media player Ajustar janela a tamanho de video

Tags: vba

Estou construindo uma skin bem simples para o windows media player. Como façopara que o vídeo abra no tamanho original? Ou seja, o WMP tem que capturar o tamanho do vídeo e já abrir em seu tamanho. Por exemplo, se um vídeo tem 200x200 o WMP já abre deste tamanho. Se o vídeo tem 400x500 o WMP já abre com esse tamanho também.. meu código....

```
        width = "640"
        height = "360"
```